# How to add filter or middleware in nginx

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, proxy, reverse

How can we add filter or middleware in nginx-server to a spring boot service or node service before it proxy_pass to another service.

```
Location /{
 Middleware or filter to some service
 Proxy_pass
}
```